# Springboot Project use AbstractRoutingDataSource question

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, shiro

My project uses springboot+springDataJpa+shiro.

Because my server database uses the master and salve method, so I need to call my code to connect to the two databases, I designed to use the AbstractRoutingDataSource + aop method. Now I have a problem, I think it may be caused by shiro.

I know that the connection switching is performed by the **getconnection()** method of **AbstractRoutingDataSource**, and I cannot manually control this method. The problem now is that my getconnection() is executed at most **twice** in an interface request. Let me post my code and describe it:

```
        @Order(0)
        @Aspect
        @Component
        public class RoutingAopAspect {
        
            @Around("@annotation(targetDataSource)")
            public Object routingWithDataSource(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, TargetDataSource targetDataSource) throws Throwable {
                try {
                    DynamicRoutingDataSourceContext.setRoutingDataSource(targetDataSource.value());
                    return joinPoint.proceed();
                } finally {
                    DynamicRoutingDataSourceContext.removeRoutingDataSource();
                }
            }
        }
    
    public class DynamicRoutingDataSourceContext {
    
        public static final String MASTER = "master";
    
        public static final String SLAVE = "slave";
    
        private static final ThreadLocal<Object> threadLocalDataSource = new ThreadLocal<>();
    
    
        public static void setRoutingDataSource(Object dataSource) {
            if (dataSource == null) {
                throw new NullPointerException();
            }
            threadLocalDataSource.set(dataSource);
            // System.err.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" set RoutingDataSource : " + dataSource);
        }
    
            public static Object getRoutingDataSource() {
                Object dataSourceType = threadLocalDataSource.get();
                if (dataSourceType == null) {
                    threadLocalDataSource.set(DynamicRoutingDataSourceContext.MASTER);
                    return getRoutingDataSource();
                }
                // System.err.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" get RoutingDataSource : " + dataSourceType);
                return dataSourceType;
            }
        
            public static void removeRoutingDataSource() {
                threadLocalDataSource.remove();
                // System.err.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" remove RoutingDataSource");
            }
        }
    
        @EnableTransactionManagement
        @Configuration
        public class DataSourceConfig {
        
            @Value("${datasource.master.url}")
            private String masterUrl;
        
            @Value("${datasource.master.username}")
            private String masterUsername;
        
            @Value("${datasource.master.password}")
            private String masterPassword;
        
            @Value("${dataSource.driverClass}")
            private String masterDriverClassName;
        
            @Value("${datasource.slave.url}")
            private String slaveUrl;
        
            @Value("${datasource.slave.username}")
            private String slaveUsername;
        
            @Value("${datasource.slave.password}")
            private String slavePassword;
        
            @Value("${dataSource.driverClass}")
            private String slaveDriverClassName;
        
            @Bean(name = "masterDataSource")
            public DataSource masterDataSource(){
                DruidDataSource datasource = new DruidDataSource();
                datasource.setUrl(masterUrl);
                datasource.setUsername(masterUsername);
                datasource.setPassword(masterPassword);
                datasource.setDriverClassName(masterDriverClassName);
                return datasource;
            }
        
            @Bean(name = "slaveDataSource")
            public DataSource slaveDataSource(){
                DruidDataSource datasource = new DruidDataSource();
                datasource.setUrl(slaveUrl);
                datasource.setUsername(slaveUsername);
                datasource.setPassword(slavePassword);
                datasource.setDriverClassName(slaveDriverClassName);
                return datasource;
            }
        
            @Primary
            @Bean
            public DynamicRoutingDataSource dynamicDataSource(@Qualifier(value = "masterDataSource") DataSource masterDataSource,
                                                              @Qualifier(value = "slaveDataSource") DataSource slaveDataSource) {
                Map<Object, Object> targetDataSources = new HashMap<>(2);
                targetDataSources.put(DynamicRoutingDataSourceContext.MASTER, masterDataSource);
                targetDataSources.put(DynamicRoutingDataSourceContext.SLAVE, slaveDataSource);
                DynamicRoutingDataSource dynamicRoutingDataSource = new DynamicRoutingDataSource();
                dynamicRoutingDataSource.setTargetDataSources(targetDataSources);
                dynamicRoutingDataSource.setDefaultTargetDataSource(masterDataSource);
                dynamicRoutingDataSource.afterPropertiesSet();
                return dynamicRoutingDataSource;
            }
        }


public class DynamicRoutingDataSourceContext {

    public static final String MASTER = "master";

    public static final String SLAVE = "slave";

    private static final ThreadLocal<Object> threadLocalDataSource = new ThreadLocal<>();


    public static void setRoutingDataSource(Object dataSource) {
        if (dataSource == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        threadLocalDataSource.set(dataSource);
        // System.err.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" set RoutingDataSource : " + dataSource);
    }

    public static Object getRoutingDataSource() {
        Object dataSourceType = threadLocalDataSource.get();
        if (dataSourceType == null) {
            threadLocalDataSource.set(DynamicRoutingDataSourceContext.MASTER);
            return getRoutingDataSource();
        }
        // System.err.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" get RoutingDataSource : " + dataSourceType);
        return dataSourceType;
    }

    public static void removeRoutingDataSource() {
        threadLocalDataSource.remove();
        // System.err.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" remove RoutingDataSource");
    }
}
```

This is the relevant basic configuration of AbstractRoutingDataSource.

I defined an aspect to get the parameters of **@TargetDataSource** in the method. This parameter is a data source that needs to be executed currently. I think there is no problem with my configuration.

Then I will use @TargetDataSource on my service method, and I use shiro, shiro’s doGetAuthorizationInfo() method and doGetAuthenticationInfo() are executed before my service, and both methods need to call my userservice .
Then the problem now is that after calling the doGetAuthorizationInfo() and doGetAuthenticationInfo() methods, they will automatically execute the getconnection() method of AbstractRoutingDataSource to switch the data source, and then execute to my own service, it will not execute the getconnection() method. , This is what I said getconnection() is executed at most twice in an interface request.

```
    @Slf4j
    @Component
    public class ShiroRealm extends AuthorizingRealm {
    
        @Autowired
        @Lazy
        private UserService userService;
        @Autowired
        CacheUtil cacheUtil;
    
        @Override
        public boolean supports(AuthenticationToken token) {
            return token instanceof JwtToken;
        }
    
        @Override
        protected AuthorizationInfo doGetAuthorizationInfo(PrincipalCollection principals) {
            String username = JwtUtil.getClaim(principals.toString(), "username");
            User user = userService.getUserByUsername(username);
            SimpleAuthorizationInfo simpleAuthorizationInfo = new SimpleAuthorizationInfo();
            simpleAuthorizationInfo.addRole(user.getRole());
            return simpleAuthorizationInfo;
        }

        @Override
        protected AuthenticationInfo doGetAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticationToken auth) {
            String token = (String) auth.getCredentials();
            String username = JwtUtil.getClaim(token, "username");
            if (username == null) {
                throw new AuthenticationException("token invalid");
            }
    
            User user = userService.getUserByUsername(username);
            if (user == null) {
                throw new AuthenticationException("User didn't existed!");
            }
            if (JwtUtil.verify(token, username, user.getPassword(), TokenType.ACCESS_TOKEN) &&
                    cacheUtil.hasKey(CacheKey.ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY + token)
            ) {
                return new SimpleAuthenticationInfo(token, token, "userRealm");
            }
            throw new AuthenticationException("Token expired or incorrect");
        }
    }


@Service
public class PageServiceImpl implements PageService {

    @Autowired
    PageRepository pageRepository;

    @Override
    @TargetDataSource("slave")
    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public List<Page> adminFindAll() {
        List<Page> pageList = pageRepository.findAll();
        if (pageList.isEmpty()) {
            throw new CustomNotFoundException("page list not found");
        }
        return pageList;
    }
}
```

I don’t know if my description is clear. If it is not clear, please ask questions. I hope to get your help, thanks very much!